# SCSS for loop variable not working

Tags: css, loops, sass

I'm trying to change the opacity of the `nth-of-type` elements with SCSS and a loop. I have tested manually setting `.slick-slide:nth-of-type(2)` and it does work just when I try it from the `@for` loop it will not take the variable `$i`. What am I doing wrong here, it seems that everything should be correct.

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    .slick-slide:nth-of-type($i) {
        opacity: 100 / $i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using a variable in a selector in SCSS you need to use the [interpolation syntax](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) and wrap it like this `#{$myVariable}`. Your example would then be:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    .slick-slide:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
        opacity: 100 / $i;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are the bomb! Thank you very much